# Define Freemarker EOL format (\n instead of \r\n)

Tags: java, spring, freemarker

In my Spring application I'm using Freemarker to generate export file - simple plain text with header and loop `<#list></#list>` to render list of items.

```
@Bean
public freemarker.template.Configuration freemarkerConfiguration() throws IOException, TemplateException {
    return new FreeMarkerConfigurationFactoryBean().createConfiguration();
}

// ...

Template template = getFreemarkerTemplate();
Writer fileWriter = getFileWriter(outputFile);

template.process(getExportData(), writer);

// flush and close writer, some additional business logic
```

I would like to set the format of the End Of Line from current Windows `\r\n` (CRLF) to Unix `\n` (LF)

What I actually tried but don't like or is not working

- Manually converting .ftl file EOL using Notepad++ - I don't want to handle my source files with many editors, there is also IntelliJ Git plugin that is converting EOL to CRLF - even if I will amend this, there is no guarantee my teammates will do this, also it may be a problem somewhere else
- Adding `<#rt>${'\n'}` at the end of every line - it's just polluting my code and developer **must** remember to add this in case of template change
- Adding `<#assign str = str?replace(...)` - seems to not be possible since this replace is working only on variables, not *current whole file* and I did not found way to render template into variable (I could create then wrapper changing EOL, but to be honest it also doesn't look like a good solutions)

Is there any **global** way to set the EOL format without manipulating each .ftl manually and separately?

Comment: Why? You need a custom writer which will convert any changing sequence to Unix format.

Comment: Writing custom writer only for such purpose sounds like huge overhead - in `Configuration` and `Template` there are many various settings including encoding - to be honest I expected that changing EOL format will be oneliner

Comment: Because you have mentioned it, you can capture output like this: `<#assign output>...generate content here...</#assign>`. But of course that would be much worse solution to the problem than filtering in the `Writer` you pass to FreeMarker.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's no such configuration option (as of 2.3.29). FreeMarker just outputs the static text part of templates as is. Though you didn't like that approach, I believe the best is to do this in the `Writer` that you pass to FreeMarker. The overhead of that won't matter at all in most applications.

The other option that avoids runtime overhead is doing the same in a custom `TemplateLoader` that wraps another `TemplateLoader`. However, the issue with such solutions is that line-breaks sometimes come from outside the templates (i.e., from the data-model), and I think users will expect those to be normalized as well.

So, even if it was a core FreeMarker feature (I guess it could be), it probably would do this on-the-fly, like you can with a custom `Writer`.

Comment: that sucks but what can I do :) By now I decided to add `<#rt>${'\n'}` at the end of every line, because it makes sense for me that template itself is a definition of what and how I want to generate data. But if my `ftl` file will get more complicated, or I will have much more of them I will definitely implement my own `Writer`. Thanks for help!

Comment: @ddekany, no it cannot be FreeMarker's duty to take care of line endings. It is a user's one. I would reject any PR doing this. At most, such a writer can land in Commons IO.